# Get user control element text from aspx page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I want to get text value of my label from user control in my aspx page to make it null.How to I access that . I tried that but this is not working

I have a pane in which user control is present

```
<%@ Register Src="~/General/Setup/UserControl/Branch.ascx" TagName="Branch" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlBranchAdd" runat="server" Width="60%">

     <div class="lgbx">
         <div class="bx_bor">
           <div id="divClose" align="right" style="height: 6px;z-index:-1;" >
          <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="Close" ImageUrl="../../Images/icn_close2.png" 
             CssClass=style3 onclick="Close_Click" Height="34px" Width="36px" />
    </div>
          <div class="content">
           <h2>
           <strong>Branch</strong></h2>
          <uc1:Branch ID="Branch" runat="server" />
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </asp:Panel>




Need help
thanks.
```

Comment: Where is the label, and what is trying to change it?  Your wording is confusing, and makes it sound like the page is trying to change a label in the usercontrol... but your code shows the other way around

Comment: Do you know what the control hierarchy is?

Comment: Also, are Master pages involved?

Comment: Yes I want to change label text in usercontrol from aspx page( code behind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this work

```
Label lbl = (Label)Branch.FindControl("LabelID");
```